# Django nonrel on Google Appengine 3000 file limit

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I followed the directions on http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine, but afterwards realized that the resulting project has almost 5,000 files, namely because of the django directory.

Am I not supposed to include django 1.3 and just use django 1.2 builtin with Google App Engine?  Or am I missing something?  I've heard that zipimport is not a good idea with django.

Comment: Should I just delete files from the django.contrib folder?

Comment: Using zipimport for this is recommended. Where have you heard that it's not a good idea?

Comment: from the nonrel page: Your instances will load slower when using zip packages because zipped Python files are not precompiled. Also, i18n doesn't work with zip packages. Zipping should only be a last resort! If you hit the 3000 files limit you should better try to reduce the number of files by, e.g., deleting unused packages from Django's "contrib" folder. Only when nothing (!) else works you should consider zip packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not a lot of solutions:

- You can try to remove every lib unnecessary in the directory of Django
- Use zipimport if you don't want use django 1.2 provides with
- GAE. Reduce the number of files you use in your project.

**But note that:** For yours instances, load a lot of files is slower because there are a lot of reads in the file system. django.zip is reads only one time and stocked in the memory to unzip it. there is just one read on the file system not 3000 and more...